# Gitlab job is successful even when the code upload to hosting platform retrieves an error

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I have a Gitlab CI/CD pipeline that uploads code to a Facebook hosting platform.

This is the stage:

```
upload:production:
  stage: upload
  before_script:
    - source ci/upload.sh
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - upload_build_to_facebook production $GAME_ID_PRODUCTION $UPLOAD_ACCESS_TOKEN_PRODUCTION
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/$GAME_ID_PRODUCTION/instant-games/hosting
```

From time to time the $UPLOAD_ACCESS_TOKEN_PRODUCTION expires and then we need a new one, although the job finishes successfully:

```
{"error":{"message":"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.","type":"OAuthException","is_transient":true,"code":2,"fbtrace_id":"<id>"}}Job succeeded
```

Is there any way to be smarter and make the job fail when I receive this kind of error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the job to be identified as failed, the script needs to return a non-zero exit state.

So, in your `upload_build_to_facebook` script you need to check whether the upload succeeded. If not, you should do `exit 1`.